# Integrate endpoints.cmd generated library from maven eclipse plugin project into android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I'm a bit of a newbie to all this.. but I can't seem to find any specific instructions for my scenario

I have built a simple endpoint api, using a maven project via eclipse.

I have built an android app, and just want to add a little test in it to use the simple api.

(sidenote: i have also built an app engine web app which will later also [i hope] make use of the same endpoint api, so both the web app and the android app make use of the same library / code)

anyway, I'm stumbling on a couple steps.

I can't seem to use the eclipse 'google -> generate cloud endpoint client library' option, since it's a maven project.
So i found on the google site, instructions to use the endpoints.cmd commandline to generate the library.
I successfully did this apparently (it created a zip file rather then just a jar)

here is where i am confused what to do next.. or if i missed something.

I have tried adding the jar within the zip as a library in the build path for my android app.
When I do that, I see that the Builder member doesn't seem to have been added.
Should I expect it to have been added by the library generation?
I can't seem to do anything in my android app code to use the library.
What am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: Ok.. i think I have confirmed the Builder member is in the jar that was created within the zip file. So i guess its just an issue with how i'm including the library.. not sure why its not resolving the class and member..

Comment: I gave up on trying to create this library through the maven plugin as a separate project.. The closest help I found was https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plugin-eclipse/P71VOt9WUBY... but it wasn't quite enough... I've gone with placing it into the GAE project, and just use the eclipse ADT plugin and choosing 'generate cloud endpoint client library' .

Comment: if anyone can still suggest how to make it work, great.. else, i used this helpful tutorial to understand how to quickly place the dependency jars and source classes into the android project properly, so my Import statements work, and I can actually start coding now (seeing the classes and members correctly).  Small difference for me was that the jars were in the libs folder in the generated library.. not the dependencies folder. That one seemed to have only html files.  http://rominirani.com/2014/01/16/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-3/